# Video sequence editor as 3d view background

Tags: video-sequence-editor

I want to render 3D objects and grease pencil animation over an image sequence i have in the Video sequence editor, Is there a way to make the video sequence editor become the background video for the 3D view?

Comment: Well you can render your VSE sequence to an image sequence or a video file, and then specify the sequence or video in the "Background Images" section of the Properties toolbar.  I'm not sure there's a way to directly pipe the current state of the VSE into the 3D view without rendering what's in the VSE.

Comment: There is no way to get the contents of the VSE directly on the 3D environment unless you render them. You can add the scene on top of the elements on the VSE, but I don't know if the grease pencil elements will show. A workaround would be to use the video as background reference in the 3D environment.  Do all of the grease pencil work and  render using a transparent background and composite the video background later.